# Can't Pass Through Value of Lookup Field on Insert

Tags: apex, lookup

I'm having trouble passing through the value of a Lookup field on Insert. I've got an object called *ts2__Project_Job__c*, which has a custom Lookup field called *Candidate__c* which looks at the Contact standard object. In my Application I simply want to use this Lookup field, to find a contact, then Insert a new record.

Here's what I've got:

**VisualForce**

```
<apex:inputField id="candidate" value="{!contactLookup.Candidate__c}" />
```

**Apex**

This is used to get the value:

```
public ts2__Project_Job__c contactLookup {
  get;
  set;
}
```

This is used to instantiate:

```
contactLookup = new ts2__Project_Job__c();
```

So far, so good. It creates the Lookup field on the VF Page and it works great! However, when trying to Insert using the following code:

```
pro.Candidate__c = candidate;
```

After initialising pro as:

```
ts2__Project_Job__c pro = new ts2__Project_Job__c();
```

I get the error:

> Illegal assignment from ts2__Project_Job__c to Id

I've tried using

```
pro.Candidate__c = candidate.Id;
```

Which will save and create the record, but won't populate the field. Debug logs show that this is blank, whereas the variable *candidate* does have an Id in there. It's just the wrong type. I've tried using:

```
Id candidate = String.valueOf(contactLookup);
```

And passing this through, but nothing happens again.

Kind of stuck on this one!

Thanks!

**Edit:** When using:

```
pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup.Id;
```

I'm getting the following in the debug logs:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: Try this one my be __r will be issue : pro.Candidate__r.id = candidate.Id;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that hasn't worked unfortunately. I should clarify doing it this way, I'm getting the debug log error: "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object".

Comment: I think you have to create new Candidate__c and contact records seprately and then attach them to each other in your save method logic.

Comment: When you have initialized pro?

Comment: @San pro is initialised just before "pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup;" using "ts2__Project_Job__c pro = new ts2__Project_Job__c();" for instance.

Comment: @susanoochidori I can't see why I'd need to do that though given contactLookup does have an Id in there. It's just the wrong type? I think basically I need to convert an SObject to an Id?

Comment: Try public ts2__Project_Job__c contactLookup = new ts2__Project_Job__c();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assignment will always fail:

```
pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup.Id;
```

Any field of type `Id` has to have the correct Id sObject type assigned to it.

Here's what I see:

- `pro` instance of `ts2__Project_Job__c` (although you don't show the instantiation, we'll just go with that assumption).
- `pro.Candidate__c` relationship field to candidate data type is `Id` of `Candidate__c` sObject type.
- `contactLookup` instance of `ts2_Project_Job__c`
- `contactLookup.Id` Id of `ts2_Project_Job__c` sObject type.

Whatever you do, you need to be assigning like for like. Going back to your code:

```
pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup.Id;
```

Here you are trying to assign the `ts2_Project_Job__c` Id value (primary key) to a relationship field that is expecting a `Candidate__c` value.

You need to assign a `Candidate__c` id value.

So that could be:

```
pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup.Candidate__c;
```

Or it could be a candidate variable from somewhere else:

```
Candidate__c candidateVariable = getCandidateInstanceFromSomewhere();

pro.Candidate__c = candidateVariable.Id;
```

It's hard to know without seeing more of your code. But I still get myself twisted around from time to time.

If you have an hour to just learn about how this all works, check out our [webinar from September 2014](https://youtu.be/J5t6XBBf3ew) that did a deep dive on this topic.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, this has been haunting me for a while now! I had no idea that Id's were also associated with SObjects. I tried converting the contactLookup to a String (worked, Id was there), to an Id (worked, showed in the debug logs), only then did I get the error regarding Id object types. Great explanation though. Thank you!

Comment: Sure...we did a webinar related to this about a year ago. I've added the link to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
pro.Candidate__c = contactLookup.Candidate__c;
```

Both `pro` and `contactLookup` are instances of `ts2__Project_Job__c` object. So when you got the contact in `Candidate__c` of `contactLookup` instance you can assign the same to `Candidate__c` of `pro` instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Vigneshwaran. This worked exactly as I needed! Only reason I've given the selected answer to Peter is because of his explanation. But, again, you're bang on with this. Thank you for looking at it!